# Division of n Identical Objects into r identical groups

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the formula $C(n-1,r-1)$ is used when we need to **distribute** n identical objects in $r$ distinct groups(such that every group receives atleast 1 object).

Suppose 10 objects need to be divided into 3 groups such that each group receives atleast one object. By using the above formula , we also consider the case such as $(1,2,7)$ $(1,7,2)$ $(2,1,7)$ $(2,7,1)$ $(7,1,2)$ $(7,2,1)$ ways.

But in this case we need to consider only one out of these possibilities.

One might think of using $C(n-1,r-1)$ and then dividing the result by $r!$. That way you should get the answer as $C(9,2)\div3! = 6$. But by writing out all the possibilities,  you get 8 different ways!

So is there any formula/algorithm to solve this?.

P.S: I have tried the following (for the above question)

1. Consider first digit to be 1 . Therefore The division is of the form $(1,x_1,x_2)$. Now we apply the above formula for solutions of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and divide it by $2!$
2. Consider first digit to be 2. Therefore the division is of the form $2,y_1,y_2$ such that $y_1>2$ and $y_2>2$ (Since the cases where $y_1$ and $y_2$ is less than or equal to 2 are already considered in step 1). We do some simple shifting of values and find the ways in which this can be done
3. Similarly we consider first digit to 3 and continue in the above manner and calculate the number of ways.
4. In the end add out the possibilities of all the cases

While this algorithm works for division into 3 groups , but it will become very long if the division is extended more.

So is there any generalised formula for doing this?

Comment: Hint: use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). For example $(1,2,7)$ would be represented by $$\star\mid\star\,\star\mid\star\,\star\,\star\,\star\,\star\,\star\,\star$$

Comment: @M.Nestor . I checked it. I works great and also simple . Thanks!

Comment: Please do not delete posts once they are answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method. Your question is

*How to distribute n identical things into r identical groups?*

Suppose you have a 10 identical objects and 3 identical groups. If you were given that the sizes of the group are in the order $g_{1}\geq g_{2}\geq g_{3}$ , you would have only considered $(7,2,1)$. Applying this for a general case.

**Algorithm: To distribute n identical objects into r(here, r=3) similar groups of differing(some maybe equal) sizes:**

Let the group sizes be denoted by $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ then $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=n$

Also, since $x_{1}\geq x_{2} \geq x_{3}$, let $$x_{1}=x_{3}+a+b$$
$$x_{2}=x_{3}+a$$
$$x_{3}=x_{3}$$

Adding $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$,

$3(x_{3}+1)+2a+b=n$ (where a,b,$x_3$ are whole numbers)

or, $3x_{3}+2a+b=n-3$

Finding the number of distinct tuples for (a,b,$x_3$) will give you the answer.

The tuples set for $n=10$ is
$\{(2,0,1),(1,0,4),(1,1,2),(1,2,0),(0,0,7),(0,1,5),(0,2,3),(0,3,1)\}$

**Algorithm: To distribute n identical objects into r similar groups of differing(some maybe equal) sizes:**

Let the group sizes be denoted by $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}...x_r$ then $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}...x_{r}=n$

Also, since $x_{1}\geq x_{2} \geq x_{3}...\geq x_{r}$,
let $$x_{r}=x_{r}$$
$$x_{r-1}=x_{r}+c_1$$
$$...$$
$$x_{1}=x_{r}+c_1+c_2+...c_r$$

Adding $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...x{r}$,

$r(x_{r}+1)...+2c_2+c_1=n$ (where $c_1,c_2,...,x_r$ are whole numbers)

or, $$rx_{r}...+2c_2+c_1=n-r$$ (where $c_1,c_2,...,x_r$ are whole numbers)

Finding the number of distinct tuples for ($c_1,c_2,...,x_r$) will give you the answer. This can be done using multinomial-theorem or a computer program if the number n and groups are large.

A follow up for the answer has been asked and can be linked here: [How to use Bars and Stars method for equations with more than 1 non unity coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772058/how-to-use-bars-and-stars-method-for-equations-with-more-than-1-non-unity-coeffi)

Comment: One of them may have an equality.  Eg (3,3,4)

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson Yes, it seems to miss, I have edited it check this out

Comment: Have added tuple set as well

Comment: Added general form

Comment: What formula did you use for finding the distinct tuples of (a,b,x3)?

Comment: You can use multinomial theorem, that'll give the direct ans. to number of such distinct tuples...And for finding tuples, i progressively eliminated the terms with high coefficients..you can look at the order as well

Comment: Since your question is not about multinomials, i will share a link wherein you can check its wiki https://brilliant.org/problems/dont-expand-it-please/

Comment: The general multinomial theory give the solutions of equation where the coefficients of terms are 1.I know there are manipulations where you could solve for 2x+y+z = k where one term has non unity coefficient. But I have never solved equations where 2 terms have non unity coefficients like 3x + 2y + z = k . Can you elaborate on how you used the multinomial theorem?

Comment: Also , Counting the solutions is out of the question because i have tried the Bars and Stars method. It has a polynomial time complexity. What i require is constant time complexity for large inputs like dividing 10000 identical objects into 100 groups.

Comment: I am not asking you to count, use the multinomial theorem, and find coefficient of $t^n$, since you claim to have solved for 2x+y+z, for solving 3x+2y+z, just do the same manipulation as you did to 2x in the previous one, or rather show your method in the question, My method will not be overly time complex, it will take hardly 2 second or 3 to solve 10 variables (using multinomial)