# How to use Bars and Stars method for equations with more than 1 non unity coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics

I know we can find the non negative integral solutions of the equation $x+y+z=24$ using Bars and Stars method.
The same can be extended to provide the solutions for equations like $2x+y+z = 24$.

But is there any way to find the non negative integral solutions of

$3x + 2y + z = 24$

and subsequently a generalised formula of non negative integral solutions of

$nx + py + qz = k$ where $n,p,q>1$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724627/general-form-for-this-problem

Comment: I assume you meant to write nonnegative integral solutions rather than non integral solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an exact solution, but since the $d$-simplex $\sum_{i=1}^da_ix_i\le k$ has volume $k^d/(d!\prod_ia_i)$ for $a_i,\,k\ge0$, $\sum_{i=1}^da_ix_i=k$ should have $\sim k^{d-1}/((d-1)!\prod_ia_i)$ solutions.

Comment: It do gives 8.333 ~= 8 which is the right answer. But do you have any links of the proof ?

Comment: Okay, This is formula amazingly works!!!.  I  now need the proof

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson For large $a_i,\,k,\,d$, it probably won't round to the exact value.

Comment: By large , do you have any limit?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson The fractional error will be $O(1/k)$, but it's hard to be more detailed than that.

Comment: In two-dimensions one can apply [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) to relate polygonal area and lattice points, but the generalization to higher dimensions is more complicated.

Comment: @hardmath [is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial) about higher dimensions complicating things.

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson The proof is 
 on https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialDistribution.html